# Google Glass GDK view error, sad cloud

Tags: android, android-view, google-glass, google-gdk

I seem to have an error in my View which results in a picture of a cloud with an unhappy face 
[image: Sad Cloud]
Nothing is being reported in the log so I'm a little lost on how to track down this error.
Are there any common problems that may lead to this?
or any suggestions on the best way to debug this sort of error?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using any voice trigger constraints, like network connectivity?

Comment: I am using a voice trigger.  But the view was working before with that.  The issue seems to be my custom view `<my.namespace.MyView android:id="@+id/someid" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="45sp" />` if i comment this out it works, but the MyView simply extends view and has a constructor and that seems to break it, and with no log statements I can't figure out why it's not working.

Comment: are you using a low-frequency LiveCard? If so, then it is because you cannot add custom Views to the limited set of supported RemoteViews.

Comment: Yep, that was exactly the problem.  I've switched over to the high-frequency method now (although it is not required fore the frequency) and it is working. @straya if you post that as an answer I'll mark it as correct for anyone else that comes up with this.  Also any advice on debugging the 'sad cloud' in future would be useful.

Comment: Also I was using a custom view to use a canvas, and I think I could have achieved this with the low-frequency method by using an ImageView and rendering the canvas to a bitmap, although I haven't tested this yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you using a low-frequency LiveCard? If so, then it is because you cannot add custom Views to the limited set of supported RemoteViews.

Note: posted from original comment, so as to get them juicy correct answer points.

Comment: Thanks, Questions with answers make the internet a happier place.

Answer (score 0):

When this happened to me, it was because I was using a 'View' which was not supported by low frequency live cards.  This was the bog standard 'View' object.  I removed it and all was well again.

Check your code for views and layouts not supported by low frequency live cards and remove them.

See https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/live-cards#creating_low-frequency_live_cards